# Calculating the Values stored in the TAG field

Tags: caching, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

Question: 
Consider a computer system that has a cache with 4096 block. Each block can store 16 bytes. What will be the value stored in the TAG field of the cache block that holds the memory block containing the address 0xABCDEF.

a. if it is Direct Mapped Cache

b. if it is 16 way set associate cache

c. if it is fully associative cache

Here is my work/logic below:

We know that each block can store 16 bytes. So that 2^4. Meaning our block offset is 4
ABCDE is 24 bits, b/c 4 bits per piece
4096 blocks is 2^12

a. is it is directly mapped then 24 - 20 - 4 --> 0

b. if its 16 way then our calculation are 24-16(index) - 4(offset) --> 4

c. if it fully associate then we do have an index and its just 24 - 4 --> 20

I am not sure if I am approaching the question the right way. Any help would be much appreciated!

I am using this illustration as my reference for how cache is represented:
 http://csillustrated.berkeley.edu/PDFs/handouts/cache-3-associativity-handout.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I figured it out.

a. Since our cache is directly mapped. We have 2^12 block blocks. That means the index will be 12, and with an offset of 4. The TAG value will be 8

b. Now since is 16 way associative. 2^4 = 16. So we do 2^12/ 2^4 ==> 2^8
This means the 8 will be in our index slot and the TAG value will be 12

c. If it is fully associative, that mean we won't have to account for the index slow. So its just 24 - 20 ==> 4

Hope this helps anyone who bumps into this